# How to center first flexbox vertically, and rest of list follows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Given this markup, the first item in the list should be vertically centered in the screen, and the rest should follow after. However, it doesn't center vertically at all. Also, it shouldn't require a hardcoded value based on the height of the item (the item should be able to have dynamic height).

```css
* {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  display: flex;
}

body > div {
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body > div > div {
  max-width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

body > div > div > div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: red;
  height: 30px;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

body > div {
  top: 50%;
}

body > div > div {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say dynamic height, is it per item so i.e. the first can be 50px, the second 100px and so on?

Comment: Btw, the `body`'s default `margin` sets it off a little in your code sample, and `body { margin: 0; }` fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the items will be dynamically sized, and to solve this using CSS alone, a small markup change is needed.

The first item will have its own wrapper, and then, with a pseudo to match the second wrapper, we can give the pseudo and the second wrapper `flex: 1` to equally share the `body`'s height, minus the first wrappers content, and with this, the first item will be centered no matter each item's size.

*The `flex-shrink: 0;` in the `body > div > div` rule prevents the items from shink to fit when there is too many.*

Stack snippet

```css
* {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {                                          /*  added rule  */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}

body::before, body > div:nth-child(2)  {        /*  added rule  */
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
}

div {
  display: flex;
}

body > div {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

body > div > div {
  max-width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;                               /*  added  */
}

body > div > div > div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: red;
  min-height: 30px;
  flex: 1;
}

/*  middle marker for this demo only  */
span {position: absolute; width: 30px; height: 50%; right: 0; background: lime; z-index: 100}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>Hey<br>Hey<br>Hey<br></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Hey<br>Hey<br>Hey<br></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>

<span>50% high</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this css for center

```
body > div:first-child {
 margin-top:20px;
}

body > div > div{
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```css
* {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  display: flex;
}

body > div {
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body > div > div {
  max-width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

body > div > div > div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: red;
  height: 30px;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

body > div:first-child {
 margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated based on your feedback. Not quite yet, see updated example. The first item is centered, but everything else is not flowing smoothly afterward (there is a gap).

Comment: Updated question with the answer based on your feedback. Thank you.

Comment: But you don't want to do center div according to screen height...?

Comment: Actually you're right, there are still bugs with it at smaller screen sizes if element is changed from 30px to say 500px.

Comment: Trying to center the first item in the list, whereas your example centers the container.